# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable; Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my code:

```
def numbers_in_lists(string):
    num = int(string)
    l = list(num)
    return l

string = '543987'
```

When i run it:

```
print numbers_in_lists(string)
```

I have the following error:

```
l = list(num)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How can i fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: What your function supposed to do?

Comment: `'int' object is not iterable` It cannot be more explicit than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`num` is an integer, and [`list()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) expects an iterable, hence the error. Did you want to obtain a list of integers representing the digits of `num`? If so you can try using [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
l = map(int, string)
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? Create a list of individual digits or a new list with a single number in it.

```
l = [int(n) for n in string]
```

or

```
l = []
l.append(int(string))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def numbers_in_lists(string):
    numbers = []
    for char in string:
        try:
            num = int(char)
            numbers.append(num)
        except:
            print 'Could not convert to number'
    return numbers

numString = '543987'
listOfNumbers = numbers_in_list(numString)
```

Here's code with exception handling in case character cant be converted to int

Answer (score 0):

like said arshajii list must have an iterable object
if you want to make a list with a not iterable object, and so here have a list with the integer as element you have to create the list like this

```
def numbers_in_lists(string):
    num = int(string)
    l = list([num])
    #or 
    l = [num]
    return l
```