# Failing to understand simple error message

Tags: python, list, int

I've defined a function as below to try to interpolate between two sets of data. When I run it, I get the message:

```
    for i, j in range(0, len(wavelength)):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Admittedly, I'm not very good at this.

```
def accountforfilter(wavelength, flux, filterwavelength, throughput):
    filteredwavelength=[]
    filteredflux=[]

    for i in range(0, len(wavelength)):
        if wavelength[i] in filterwavelength[j]:
            j=filterwavelength.index(wavelength[i])
            filteredwavelength.append(wavelength[i])
            filteredflux.append(flux[i]*throughput[j])

        elif wavelength[i]<filterwavelength[j]<wavelength[i+1]:
            m=((throughput[j+1]-throughput[j])/(filterwavelength[j+1]-filterwavelength[j])
            c=throughput[j]-(m*(wavelength[i]))
            filteredwavelength.append(wavelength[i])
            filteredflux.append(flux[i]*(m*wavelength[i]+c)

    return filteredwavelength, filteredflux
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830145/typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable-python-2-7

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523563/python-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable

Comment: Your traceback does *not* match the code you posted. Are you sure you are running the same code?

Comment: I copied and pasted the code, so I assume I must be running the same as what is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`range()` returns a list of integers. By using `for i,j in range()` you are telling Python to unpack each item in `range()` to two values. But since those values are integers, which are a single piece of data, and thus not iterable, you get the error message.

Your code also looks a bit strange.
At first it seems like you want to loop over all combinations of wavelength/filterwavelength, which would be the same as

```
for i in range(len(wavelength)):
    for j in range(len(filterwavelength)):
         do_stuff()
```

but then you are modifying the `j` parameter inside the loop body, which I don't understand.

Regardless, there is probably a lot easier, and more clear, way to write the code you want. But from the current code it is hard to know what is expected (and should probably go in a separate question).

Comment: So if I instead replace that line with two if statements, one for i and one for j, would that work?

Comment: @NXW that depends, what are you trying to get `i` and `j` to be? You could use e.g. `for i, j in itertools.product(range(len(wavelenth)), repeat=2)` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the range only works with one variable like so:

```
for i in range(0, len(wavelength))
```

You try to use two variables at once so python tries to *unpack* an integer which is impossible. You should use the above. If you need two independent indices, use

```
for i in range(0, len(...))
  for j in range(0, len(...))
```

Btw ranges always start with zero so you can save yourself some typing and use `range(len(...))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` if you want.

check this: [Better way to iterate over two or multiple lists at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080379/better-way-to-iterate-two-multiple-lists-at-once)

if you have two sets of data.

```
for i,j in zip(set1,set2):
print i,j
```